# Странный формат записи SQL-запроса с PDO в PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день! В учебном примере написания чата на PHP с использованием PDO для SQL-запросов столкнулся со следующей странностью в функции добавления новых сообщений:

```
$query = $this->_db->prepare("INSERT INTO `messages` (`time`, `message`, `uid`) VALUES(?,?,?)");
```

Что означает VALUES(?,?,?)? Что будет вставлено в таблицу БД после такого запроса?

Answer (score 1):

Очень странный учебный пример, который не объясняет принципов излагаемого материала.

Для начала, никакой PDO в этом примере не используется, а используется mysqli.
Впрочем, сути ответа это не меняет. Знаки вопроса - это плейсхолдеры, на место которых будут подставлены данные.

Данный формат служит для выполнения динамических запросов - то есть таких, в которых используются переменные. Поскольку из соображений безопасности переменные нельзя писать в запрос напрямую, вместо переменных пишутся знаки вопроса. А сами переменные передаются отдельно. И это единственно правильный способ передавать переменные в запрос.

Такой формат поддерживают все современные библиотеки для работы с БД, разница только в конкретной реализации, подробности которой следует смотреть в документации.

Тем не менее, следует отметить, что mysqli является менее удобной библиотекой для конечного пользователя, и если выбирать между ней и PDO, то последняя является более предпочтительной. В частности, "смысл заморочки с bind" состоит в том, что эта функция копирует поведение низкоуровневого API, предоставляемого Мysql. То есть, с одной стороны, строго следует спецификации, но с другой - делает привязку переменных неудобной. В то время как PDO, являясь более высоким уровнем абстракции, предлагает различные упрощения - такие как передача параметров прямо в execute().
Впрочем, и PDO, в свою очередь, является далеко не идеальной библиотекой, и также не рекомендуется к использованию напрямую.

Отдельно хочу отметить, что документация - куда более правильный источник информации, чем всякие "учебные примеры", написанные неизвестно кем. Информацию оп любой интересующей функции следует смотреть в документации. Просто набрав в гугле ее название, и перейдя по ссылке, в которой будет php.net.

Пример:

- Нас интересует функция bind_param.
- Идем в гугль, и пишем bind_param
- Первой ссылкой идет http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
- Переходим по ссылке и читаем как объяснение, так и корректный пример использования.

Очень просто и в то же время чрезвычайно эффективно

Comment: Ок... а учебный пример "Пишем чат на PHP+AJAX" вот:
http://mzcoding.com/php_practice/chat_na_php_plus_ajax_s_nulya/7/

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php

Подготавливает SQL запрос к базе данных к запуску посредством метода PDOStatement::execute(). **Запрос может содержать** именованные (:name) или **неименованные (?) псевдопеременные**, которые будут заменены реальными значениями во время запуска запроса на выполнение.

И пример от сюда http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php

```
<?php
/* Выполнение подготовленного запроса с передачей массива входных значений */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
$sth->execute(array($calories, $colour));
?>
```

Comment: В данном примере интересно что $query->execute() вообще без передачи параметров, зато переменные скорее всего вот так передаются: $query->bind_param('isi', $time, $message, $uid)

В чем может быть смысл заморочки с bind вместо передачи в execute()?

Comment: @NDanilov2015, с помощью $query->bind_param() идет как раз привязка псевдопеременных из $this->_db->prepare() к переменным, которые надо передать в запрос. На этой странице 2й пример посмотрите http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: @NDanilov2015 "В чем может быть смысл заморочки с bind вместо передачи в execute()"  -- полагаю, что в понятности, удобочитаемости. Разнести последовательные шаги на отдельные строчки кода - логично.